# Python: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python

This script is used to execute a LEND order in Kucoin. It is partially taken from https://github.com/Kucoin/kucoin-python-sdk/blob/master/kucoin/margin/margin.py .
When I run this Python script I get "NameError: name 'self' is not defined".

```
#pip install kucoin-python
from kucoin.client import Margin

self.key = "610...d1"
self.secret = "e32...766"
self.passphrase = "n..7T"

order = self.client.create_lend_order(
    currency="USDT",
    size="18",
    dailyIntRate="0.080",
    term="28",
)
print(order)

def create_lend_order(self, currency, size, dailyIntRate, term):
    """
    https://docs.kucoin.com/#post-lend-order
    :param currency: Currency to lend (Mandatory)
    :type: str
    :param size: Total size (Mandatory)
    :type: str
    :param dailyIntRate: Daily interest rate. e.g. 0.002 is 0.2% (Mandatory)
    :type: str
    :param term: Term (Unit: Day) (Mandatory)
    :type: int
    :return:
    {
        "orderId": "5da5a4f0f943c040c2f8501e"
    }
    """
    params = {
        'currency': currency,
        'size': size,
        'dailyIntRate': dailyIntRate,
        'term': term
    }
    return self._request('POST', '/api/v1/margin/lend', params=params)

def _request(self, method, uri, timeout=5, auth=True, params=None):
    uri_path = uri
    data_json = ''
    version = 'v1.0.7'
    if method in ['GET', 'DELETE']:
        if params:
            strl = []
            for key in sorted(params):
                strl.append("{}={}".format(key, params[key]))
            data_json += '&'.join(strl)
            uri += '?' + data_json
            uri_path = uri
    else:
        if params:
            data_json = json.dumps(params)

            uri_path = uri + data_json

    headers = {}
    if auth:
        now_time = int(time.time()) * 1000
        str_to_sign = str(now_time) + method + uri_path
        sign = base64.b64encode(
            hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf-8'), str_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
        if self.is_v1api:
            headers = {
                "KC-API-SIGN": sign,
                "KC-API-TIMESTAMP": str(now_time),
                "KC-API-KEY": self.key,
                "KC-API-PASSPHRASE": self.passphrase,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        else:
            passphrase = base64.b64encode(
                hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf-8'), self.passphrase.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
            headers = {
                "KC-API-SIGN": sign,
                "KC-API-TIMESTAMP": str(now_time),
                "KC-API-KEY": self.key,
                "KC-API-PASSPHRASE": passphrase,
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "KC-API-KEY-VERSION": "2"
            }
    headers["User-Agent"] = "kucoin-python-sdk/" + version
    url = urljoin(self.url, uri)

    if method in ['GET', 'DELETE']:
        response_data = requests.request(method, url, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
    else:
        response_data = requests.request(method, url, headers=headers, data=data_json,
                                         timeout=timeout)
    print(response_data)
```

So I added these lines to the start of the script:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.key = "610...d1"
    self.secret = "e32...766"
    self.passphrase = "n..7T"
```

But then I get similar errors on the other "self" statements in the script (self.create).
What else would I need to add to the SELF definition
OR
Is there a way to call the script without the SELF variables.

Comment: Your `create_lend_order` would need to be part of a class for `self` to make sense (e.g. see the docs on [Python classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)). Currently it appears to be defined as part of a regular function.

Comment: If you can explain more about where the code came from and what it is supposed to do, then it might be easier for somebody to provide helpful advice.  It looks like your code snippet has been taken out of context with some key parts missing.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html would be good to read through.

Comment: @TMBailey This script is used to execute a LEND order in Kucoin. It is partially taken from https://github.com/Kucoin/kucoin-python-sdk/blob/master/kucoin/margin/margin.py

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet in the question would be appropriate as part of a class.  For that to work it would have to be indented within a `class` definition.  Alternatively, the method definitions could be converted to ordinary function definitions without the `self` arguments.

Commenters have helpfully linked to a [tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Python code that references the variable `self` is almost always part of a class.  Within a class, "functions" that act on the class are called *methods*, and they are defined by function definitions with an argument in the first argument position that is usually called `self`.

The code snippet `def create_lend_order(self, ...)` is trying to define a class method.  This should be within a class definition like so:

```
class MyClass():
    """This is a class definition"""
    def create_lend_order(self, currency, size, dailyIntRate, term):
        """This is a method definition"""
        pass  # Replace this with code to do something.
```

References to `self`, like `self.key` and so forth, generally only make sense within a class method.

Alternatively, the code could potentially be converted to ordinary functions and variables (`key` rather than `self.key`) rather than classes.  This would look like so:

```
key = "610...d1"

def create_lend_order(currency, size, dailyIntRate, term):
    """This is a function definition."""
    pass  # Replace this with code to do something.
```

Comment: Thanks @TMBailey Yes ordinary functions and Variables would be better than classes (which I am guessing would eliminate the SELF completely). I see your reference to replace self.client.create_lend_order, although how would I go about replacing the other SELF references, specifically: 1) "self._request" 2) def _request(self, method, uri, timeout=5, auth=True, params=None) 3) self.is_v1api

Comment: Seems like morphing into one or more bigger questions.  What are you actually trying to accomplish, and why do you think pulling a few class methods out of context and changing them to functions will help?

Comment: I am only trying to get the script to work. I though removing the SELF would have resolved the issue quicker and cleaner, although at this stage I dont really care if the SELF is there or not. In that case how would I define 1) "self._request" 2) def _request(self, method, uri, timeout=5, auth=True, params=None)